# Why won't my 3' extension 15amp cord plug into a GFCI outlet? It appears the round ground on the extension cord is longer than 2 blades. Solutions?

Tags: wiring

The GFCI outlet is mounted to the outside of the home with a plastic protective cover.
I want to plug a 2 prong adapter for a Ring Camera extension cord into this GFCI outlet. The two prong adapter block will not plug into the GFCI outlet.
I suspect it is because the outlet requires the male plug to have a ground as well as it appears anything plugging into a GFCI outlet has to have all male parts(including the ground) be the same length in order to open the closed gates at the same time on the GFCI outlet.
I have ordered 2 different extension cords 15amp. On both cords, the ground is longer than the blades and so the gates on the GFCI outlet will not open.
Looking for solutions without rewiring.

Comment: Longer ground prongs are standard.  Do not use safety receptacles/outlets, but my understanding is they use the ground going in first to open the gates.  Pictures of the plugs and outlet please.

Comment: Just keep trying with the 2-prong until it finally goes in.

Comment: Is it a tamper proof outlet?

Answer (score 2):

Your GFCI outlet probably has anti-tamper shutters inside the two power & neutral slots. If your outlet does not have a shutter in the ground hole it is probably like mine.

My GFCI anti-tamper outlets do not require a 3-prong plug. A two prong plug will go in. You just have to get the pressure exactly balanced and coordinated on the two-prong plug. Both prongs have to hit the shutters at exactly the same time to get the shutters to open and let the plug in.

A brand-new outlet may require more pressure than usual on the ground plug.

Comment: Look for `TR` in a box outline on the outlet - that will indicate that it's tamper resistant. The proper phrasing for that, IMHO, is "use resistant", but... maybe that's just me.

Comment: Like many things, some seem to be well made and work as they should, and others can't seem to tell the difference between a legitimate plug and a 3 year old with a paperclip. But I guess even those protect the 3 year old, until they get ripped out for being useless to people with actual plugs they've tried 20 times without the [expletive] outlet permitting it to go in.